# Lower the creating new tags bar for experienced users

Tags: feature-request, tags, new-users, tag-creation

I have just asked a question about [Hebrew Fonts in Mac](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/61713/microsoft-true-type-fonts-on-mac). The question should clearly be tagged with a `Hebrew` tag, but I don't have the rep to create it. This is a bit frustrating, because creating this tag would obviously improve AskDifferent.

I added a comment on my question asking for this tag, and it will probably be created soon, but this seems a bit unfair - someone else will earn the [Taxonomist badge](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/11/taxonomist) for this tag.

Perhaps we should lower the reputation bar for creating tags for users with lots of reputation in any other SE site?

Comment: What if they only have that one account?

Comment: How does one tag improve a site?

Comment: I even wonder if that tag is truly necessary.

Comment: It's only 300 rep that you need for creating tags on Ask Different.. Is it too much to ask you get to know the community and topics of that site first?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tagging is far more difficult than it seems on first glance. There have been endless discussions, often pretty intense ones, about tagging on the whole SE network. Deciding which tags are useful often requires a deep understanding of the site and experience with the subject. And even then we often create and use tags that are later found to be useless or even harmful.

I have more than 10k reputation on three SE sites, and I'm a moderator on two. I still would not want to create a new tag on a site I don't know very well even if I could. The chance that I create a bad tag is pretty high because I don't yet understand the tagging principles the sites uses, and I don't know all the old discussions about tagging on that site.

As a specific example take tagging on Arqade (Gaming), there have been numerous heated discussions about tagging there, and the tagging principles there are not really obvious to a new user.

It's very easy to create bad tags, so a certain barrier to creating them is necessary. I even think we need better ways to review and sort out bad tags before they proliferate.